# Lost money on credit card refund due to exchange rates & fees

Tags: credit-card, banking, foreign-exchange, refund

My CC had an unauthorized charge by an overseas service I was undergoing a free trial with. They apologised and refunded that amount (and I subsequently cancelled the free trial), but I lost money due to foreign exchange fees.

What can I do here? I've requested them to cover my losses but they are refusing to at the moment. Since the initial charge to my CC was unauthorized, does that allow me some other avenue to get my losses covered by them?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178781/4171

Answer (score 4):

The company made a charge on your credit card, and they have refunded exactly what they charged. The foreign exchange fees are from your bank.

If you have asked the company to give you extra to cover the foreign exchange fees and they have refused, I don’t know how you would make them pay without suing them in a foreign country, which is certainly not worth it.

Instead, you should call your bank (credit card company) and ask them if they would refund you the foreign exchange fees for this transaction. They may or may not, but it won’t hurt to ask.

Comment: WRT the exchange rate itself, the OP could have as easily made a profit.  I somehow doubt there's an SE question about refunding the excess :-)

Comment: @jamesqf The point is that this was an unauthorized transaction according to the Fair Credit Billing Act