Double Currency Exchange Fee charges after Refund
I made a purchase for an airline ticket and my flight was cancelled. The company refunded me but the problem is that I paid currency exchange fees worth of approximately 100$ both ways. What can I do now? My issue keep in mind is not with the exchange rate which is approximately the same in both payments but with the 6% fees the bank charged me. Do banks ever waive the fees in such cases?

Similar:  https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124824/32127  (Not a dupe because that one is about an unauthorized charge, not a legitimate charge that is being refunded.)

https://money.stackexchange.com/q/116749/32127

You'll need to talk to your bank.
Some do, especially if the refund is coded as a refund transaction. That would appear as a cancellation, reversal of the charge (in the system, not to you in the statement).
Others don't, especially if the refund is coded as a credit transaction. That would appear as a separate independent unrelated transaction in the system.

Ok that is good, I got an sms that it is a transaction cancellation, not a new credit transaction.
